# Android Dialog with Positive/Negative and a Tickbox

Tags: android

Trying to find a way to create an alert dialog, either using in Android built in, or 3rd party library that allows me to create an Alert dialog with a title, a description, 2 custom reponses (Option A, Option B), and a "don't show this again" checkbox.

I can't see to be able to do all these things, I can do them in various ways, but not all at the same time.  Even the multitude of custom alert dialogs don't seem to be able to.  I can have text and checbox but only a positive response.  I checked out a few, and they all seem limited in the same way.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this guide on dialogs: [Creating a Custom Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#CustomLayout)

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To combine text message and checkbox you should use custom dialog layout.

Create new layout resource file `dialog_content.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/dialog_message" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/dialog_content_check_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/do_not_show_again" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use this layout to build alert dialog in your Activity/Fragment

```kotlin
val dialogContentView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_content, null)
val checkBox = dialogContentView.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.dialog_content_check_box)
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
    if (isChecked) {
        // CheckBox is checked
    } else {
        // CheckBox is unchecked
    }
}

AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
    .setView(dialogContentView)
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.reject) { dialog, which ->
        // Negative button clicked
    }
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept) { dialog, which ->
        // Positive button clicked
    }
    .show()
```